# Unable to install the node packages in azure

Tags: node.js, windows, azure

I am unable to install the node modules in azure (App Service Web Apps). This error comes up frequently when i have to update the node modules while deploying from local git. It's weird as this error does not show up everytime. After I try a couple of times the modules get installed.

```
remote: npm ERR! git submodule -q update --init --recursive:       0 [main] sh 26552 fork: child -1 - CreateProcessW failed for 'D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\usr\bin\sh.exe', errno 13
remote: npm ERR! git submodule -q update --init --recursive: D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\mingw32/libexec/git-core\git-submodule: fork: Permission denied
remote: npm ERR! git submodule -q update --init --recursive: D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\mingw32/libexec/git-core\git-submodule: line 7: /usr/bin/basename: Permission denied
remote: npm ERR! git submodule -q update --init --recursive:       0 [main] sh 23252 fork: child -1 - CreateProcessW failed for 'D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\usr\bin\sh.exe', errno 13
remote: npm ERR! git submodule -q update --init --recursive: /mingw32/libexec/git-core/git-sh-setup: fork: Permission denied
remote: npm ERR! git submodule -q update --init --recursive:
remote: npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.2.9200
remote: npm ERR! argv "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\6.2.2\\node.exe" "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\npm\\3.9.5\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--production
```

Comment: Please edit your question with more details, such as... where you're deploying your app (web apps?), and how you're deploying. Right now, anything suggested would just be a guess.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I am deploying a web app from local git.

Comment: Do you have a git url in package.json ? your error doesnt show which module is failing. can you share your package.json.  https://prmadi.com/azure-custom-deployment/ link might help you understand how git deployment works for nodejs app

Comment: Do you have any custom operation like `git submodule -q update --init --recursive`? Could you remove `-q` options to output all messages via the installation for tracing the issue.